# How to store different objects, that are of the same parent, in one array? C++

Tags: c++, arrays, oop, inheritance

I have a Vheicle class and it's child classes Bus, Helicopter, Train.
Is there a way to store all the Bus, Helicopter, Train objects in one array together?
I have looked on internet and didn't find any working solution.

This is my code:

Class declaration:

```
class Vehicle {
private:
    string vehicleID;
    string man;
public:
    Vehicle(string, string);
    Vehicle();

    virtual ~Vehicle();
};

class Bus: public Vehicle
{
public:
    int currentMileage;
    Bus(string, string, int);
    Bus();

    virtual ~Bus();


};
class Train: public Vehicle
{
public:
    char motorType;
    Train(string, string, char);
    Train();

    virtual~Train();
};


Vehicle::Vehicle(string id, string m) {
    vehicleID = id;
    man = m;
}

Bus::Bus(string id, string m, int curMile): Vehicle{id,m}{
    currentMileage = curMile;
}

Train::Train(string id, string m, char mType):Vehicle(id,m){
    motorType = mType;
}
```

I need this working:

```
    //method not related to this question
    vehicleData bus = getBus(s1);


    Vehicle* arrVehicle[2];
    arrVehicle[0] = new Bus(bus.vehicleID, bus.man, bus.curMileage);


    printf("%i\n", arrVehicle[0]->currentMileage);
    printf("%c\n", arrVehicle[0]->man);
```

this is the error I am getting

```
   ‘class Vehicle’ has no member named ‘currentMileage’
```

I have tried a few things on interenet and nothing worked... Erroring something similar to the above.

Would appreciate you answering.

Comment: You miss one important point: Every `Bus` is a `Vehicle`, but not every `Vehicle` is a `Bus`, thus not every vehicle has a member `currentMileage`. Should `currentMileage` maybe be part of `Vehicle`?

Comment: In order to print specific data members from the array, you'll need to cast to the appropriate object, then access the specifics.

Comment: Your question title is going to confuse readers. Your question is essentially about object hierarchy, but the title talks about arrays.

Comment: @churill No, it should not be the part of `Vehicle`, it doesn't metter what it's called, I just need the `Bus` object with all it's properties in the array and `Train` object with all it's properties in the same array.

So i don't miss anything.

It seems like every `Bus` is only a Vehicle and every `Train` is only a `Vehicle` and not a `Train` or `Bus` after it's added to array.
And this was a question how to store different childs of the same parent together in one array.

Comment: @SergeyA That's so wierd. The title talks about same-parent objects in array. And the question is about child objects in array.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews What do you mean 'cast object'? I am creating `Bus` object and it's child of `Vehicle`, then trying to access `Bus`'s own properties but I can access only `Vehicle`'s properties for some reason... Thats what the question is about.

Comment: Because the array is of type `Vehicle *`, you can only access items from the `Vehicle` class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to achieve what you're trying to do is to cast that `Vehicle*` to `Bus*`

```cpp
vehicleData bus = getBus(s1);

Vehicle* arrVehicle[2];
arrVehicle[0] = new Bus(bus.vehicleID, bus.man, bus.curMileage);

// First method
printf("%i\n", dynamic_cast<Bus*>(arrVehicle[0])->currentMileage);
printf("%c\n", dynamic_cast<Bus*>(arrVehicle[0])->man);

// Second method, don't need to cast everytime
Bus* busInstance = dynamic_cast<Bus*>(arrVehicle[0]);

printf("%i\n", busInstance->currentMileage);
printf("%c\n", busInstance->man);
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar requirement in the past and I reach the solution by creating a double pointer array that contains pointers to your different vehicles:

```cpp
//When adding a new vehicle to your array you will need an aux array in order to update the list in a dynamic way

Vehicle **aux = new Vehicle *[vehicle_counter+1]; 

//Then create the new vehicle type with the constructor and it parameters

Bus *_Bus; 
_Bus= new Bus(vehicle_id,man,currentMileage);

//Finally use this loop to update your vehicle list

for (int i=0;i<vehicle_counter;i++){  list
  aux[i]=list_vehicles[i]; //Adding the current objects in the list to the aux array
}

//Adding the new vehicle of Bus type (aux has +1 space that the current list)

aux[vehicle_counter] = _Bus; 
vehicle_counter++;
list_vehicles=aux; //Updating the list of vehicles with the new vehicle added
```

Doing this you will be able to access to different objects/parameters individually and you array that contains the different vehicles (the list) will remain dynamic.